# How to make hovering text for a custom coordinates in Rust using egui?

Tags: user-interface, rust, egui

I'm trying to make visualization for iterative algorithm, using `macroquad` and `egui`. Pure plot on `macroquad` looks like this:
[image]

Note that each circle or vertice is a `struct` instance with `N` fields, content from which I want to appear with hovering over the circle's perimeter?

How can I do it? Which way is more elegant/better to use? I think of writing custom widget for each circle and therefore hovering on this widget. But it seems complicated — I have a lot of circles thus need a lot of widgets. Probably better would be using some fields, where if user clicked, window appeared with information.

Any help is really appreciated